# What autotest tools exist for Clojure

Tags: clojure, autotest

I was wondering what autotest tools exists for clojure. In Ruby I have ZenTest, redgreeen etc to continuously keep on testing my code. I would like to have something similar for Clojure

So far I have found this simple script https://github.com/devn/clojure-autotest on the github. A bit crude for my taste. All tests run when a change occurrs. Also it may blurt out a long stacktrace in case of syntax errors, obscuring what goes wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the Testing section on the [Leiningen plugin page](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Plugins).

Notably there's [lein-autotest](https://github.com/dakrone/lein-autotest) for Stuart Sierras [lazytest](https://github.com/stuartsierra/lazytest) framework and [speclj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Plugins).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `clojure.test` there are a few options available. [lein-test-refresh](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh) is what I use (I'm also the author). Other options include [quickie](https://github.com/jakepearson/quickie) and [prism](https://github.com/aphyr/prism/).

If you use [expectations](https://github.com/jaycfields/expectations) then there is [lein-autoexpect](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-autoexpect). I'm also the author of that.

Midje has built in support for autotesting. I'm not sure what the options are for Speclj.